# DHARMA to detect overdispersion in negative binomial

Tags: residuals, negative-binomial-distribution, glmm, overdispersion

I'm new to negative binomial GLMMs and still trying to get a hold of checking my residuals. DHARMa has been a huge help, but I still am having some inconsistent results. I am looking at three groups of predictor variables (insects, vegetation, and environmental) and attempting to discover the parameters that most impact bat activity (count data with an offset for # of survey days and random variable for Site). My scaled and centered dataset looks something like:

```
 $ Year             : Factor w/ 2 levels "2017","2018"
 $ Reampled         : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes"
 $ Habitat          : Factor w/ 4 levels "MCF","MM","MMF","REGEN"
 $ Site             : Factor w/ 63 levels "MCF_001","MCF_002",...
 $ Disturbed        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Disturbed","Mature"
 $ Species          : Factor w/ 3 levels "MYLU","MYSE", "NoID"
 $ Count            : int  1 3 0 1 0 0 6 38 3 43 ...
 $ Bat.Survey.Nights: int  4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 4 ...
 $ Avg.Coleoptera   : num  -0.201 -0.201 -0.201 -0.336 -0.336 ...
 $ Avg.Diptera      : num  -0.33 -0.33 -0.33 -0.579 -0.579 ...
 $ Avg.Hemiptera    : num  -0.42 -0.42 -0.42 -0.42 -0.42 ...
 $ Avg.Hymenoptera  : num  2.91 2.91 2.91 -0.497 -0.497 ...
 $ Avg.Lepidoptera  : num  -0.448 -0.448 -0.448 -0.369 -0.369 ...
 $ Avg.Other        : num  -0.448 -0.448 -0.448 -0.306 -0.306 ...
 $ Avg.Trichoptera  : num  0.0486 0.0486 0.0486 -0.3353 -0.3353 ...
 $ Avg.Biomass      : num  -0.382 -0.382 -0.382 -0.484 -0.484 ...
 $ Shannon.Weaver   : num  -0.6444 -0.6444 -0.6444 0.0588 0.0588 ...
 $ Num.Orders       : num  0.0714 0.0714 0.0714 -1.9005 -1.9005 ...
 $ Avg.Snags        : num  -0.855 -0.855 -0.855 1.846 1.846 ...
 $ Avg.Understory   : num  -0.00715 -0.00715 -0.00715 -0.94871 -0.94871 ...
 $ Avg.Midstory     : num  -0.352 -0.352 -0.352 0.256 0.256 ...
 $ Avg.Canopy       : num  -1.061 -1.061 -1.061 0.695 0.695 ...
 $ Avg.Canopy.Cover : num  -0.831 -0.831 -0.831 0.506 0.506 ...
 $ Perc.Dec.Dom     : num  -0.493 -0.493 -0.493 -1.095 -1.095 ...
 $ Avg.Bat.Date     : num  -0.772 -0.772 -0.772 -1 -1 ...
 $ Avg.Bat.Night.Hr : num  -0.841 -0.841 -0.841 -0.956 -0.956 ...
 $ Avg.Bat.Temp     : num  0.523 0.523 0.523 -0.559 -0.559 ...
 $ Bat.Dist.Edge    : num  -0.882 -0.882 -0.882 -0.434 -0.434 ...
 $ Bat.Elevation    : num  -0.743 -0.743 -0.743 -0.577 -0.577 ...
 $ Bat.Moon         : num  0.665 0.665 0.665 -0.284 -0.284 ...
 $ Bat.Dist.Water   : num  1.075 1.075 1.075 0.951 0.951 ...
 $ Bat.Water.Feat   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Lake","River", "Stream"
```

I ran all the models and was left with a best model, which I know, is quite complex:

```
glmm.nbin.all.3 <- glmer.nb(Count ~ Avg.Biomass + Num.Orders + Shannon.Weaver + 
Species + Avg.Snags + Avg.Understory + Avg.Midstory + Avg.Canopy.Cover + 
Perc.Dec.Dom + Avg.Understory*Species + Avg.Midstory*Species + 
Avg.Canopy.Cover*Species + (Avg.Bat.Date*Avg.Bat.Temp)^2 + Bat.Elevation + 
Bat.Moon + Bat.Water.Feat*Species + offset(log(Bat.Survey.Nights)) + (1|Site), 
data = insect.data)
```

Before I found the DHARMa package, I was using a dispersion test (https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/224), which results in:

```
m1 <- glmmtmb.nbin.all.3

dispfun <- function(m) {
  r <- residuals(m,type="pearson")
  n <- df.residual(m)
  dsq <- sum(r^2)
  c(dsq=dsq,n=n,disp=dsq/n)
}
options(digits=4)
dispfun(m1)

    dsq       n    disp 
189.153 177.000   1.069
```

This indicates a slight overdispersion; I realize 1.06 isn't that much >1, but I wanted to double-check. However, when I look at DHARMa's output, it does not seem to indicate overdispersion. Which output should I be focusing on?

```
all.res3 <- simulateResiduals(glmm.nbin.all.3)
plot(all.res3)
testResiduals(all.res3)

$uniformity

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  simulationOutput$scaledResiduals
D = 0.053, p-value = 0.6
alternative hypothesis: two-sided


$dispersion

    DHARMa nonparametric dispersion test via sd of residuals fitted vs. simulated

data:  simulationOutput
ratioObsSim = 0.76, p-value = 0.7
alternative hypothesis: two.sided


$outliers

    DHARMa outlier test based on exact binomial test

data:  simulationOutput
outLow = 0.000, outHigh = 1.000, nobs = 207.000, freqH0 = 0.004, p-value = 0.9
alternative hypothesis: two.sided


$uniformity

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  simulationOutput$scaledResiduals
D = 0.053, p-value = 0.6
alternative hypothesis: two-sided


$dispersion

    DHARMa nonparametric dispersion test via sd of residuals fitted vs. simulated

data:  simulationOutput
ratioObsSim = 0.76, p-value = 0.7
alternative hypothesis: two.sided


$outliers

    DHARMa outlier test based on exact binomial test

data:  simulationOutput
outLow = 0.000, outHigh = 1.000, nobs = 207.000, freqH0 = 0.004, p-value = 0.9
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

[image]

It also doesn't ease my worries when the residuals plots differ and sometimes there is a hump shape to them (pictures below of the same model). Does anyone have any suggestions on whether this model upholds the assumptions?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dispersion values will never be exactly 1, due to random variation in the data. Both tests don't seem to indicate overdispersion, although I would note that you don't really know for the function that you use, as it doesn't produce p-values. I believe performance::check_overdispersion is based on the same idea as your parametric test, but has p-values, so you could try this out if you want to check significance.

Note also my comments here [Overdispersion tests from DHARMa and sjstats: conflicting results?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409179/overdispersion-tests-from-dharma-and-sjstats-conflicting-results/417688) as well as https://github.com/florianhartig/DHARMa/issues/117

Comment: thanks so much! I tried the performance check and there is no overdispersion